# Some Javascript is blocking favicon icon

Tags: javascript, favicon

I am working on a Backbone application. I am trying to show favicon but it is not appearing there. If  I disable javascript, favicon comes up at its place.

Comment: What is the question? What does your code look like? Do you get an error message? Etc.

Comment: no, In some page its appearing and in some its not. there is no error. I can see proper link tag in head too.

Comment: Show some code or issue details.